# Mock Database.GetDbConnection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

Please help with ideas how can i mock `someDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()`?

Currently i have repository pattern and the only concrete database context, which injected there. And in unit tests i want to test behavior of AddSomeEntity abd RemoveSomeEntity method, where, exactly, i use `someDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()` to get **dbConnection** and after that create **dbCommand** and execute it.

I know few ways how i can solve this problem: add abstraction or some logic in repository class, but it seems like overcomplicated. So i'm asking for any ideas, how can i mock this method call directly in unit test class without adding any classes or method in source class.

I'm using EF Core 6, xUnit, Moq and FluentAssertions, i tried, but there wasn't appropriate solution.

How i currently mock **db context**

```
contextMock.Setup(x => x.SomeDbSet)
        .ReturnsDbSet(new List<SomeEntity>
        {
            new()
            {
                // initialization of class fields 
            }
        });
```

Comment: [Testing EF Core Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Repository pattern, that is the perfect boundary for unit testing/mocking. Unit tests test business logic so the repository is the one mocked to provide known data state and/or assert that proper calls are made to persist data state.

In my case my repositories leverage `IQueryable` so I utilize MockQueryable.Moq now for wrapping known sets as `IQueryable` to work with both synchronous and asynchronous consumption.

To test the repository implementation itself, that I would recommend treating at an integration test level using a live data source. This could be a database which a pre-known initial data state or an in-memory database. The behaviour of in-memory databases can differ from actual databases so I tend to use backup DB images for integration tests.

Comment: thanks, but i wanna mock this method in unit test.